# Can I programmatically collapse/expand all preprocessor blocks of a certain name in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

My current project has a lot of debug preprocessor blocks scattered throughout the code. These are intentionally named differently to the system _DEBUG and NDEBUG macros, so I have a lot of this:

```
// Some code here

#ifdef PROJNAME_DEBUG
//unit tests, assumption testing, etc.
#endif

// code continues
```

These blocks sometimes get rather large, and their presence can sometimes inhibit code readability. In Visual Studio 2012 I can easily collapse these, but it would be nice to automatically have *all of them* collapsed, allowing me to expand them if I want to see what's in there. However, as I also have a bunch of header guards I don't want to collapse all preprocessor blocks, only the #ifdef PROJNAME_DEBUG ones.

Can I do this?

Comment: @GManNickG Ok I've adjusted the tags to make it more suitable.

Comment: @GManNickG: questions about the IDE are on-topic here. An IDE is a tool which is only used by people doing programming.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: Looks like you're right, my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

This is the most easiest scenario you can achive it, I think.

You should create an Add-In first in C#. (in VS 2013 they become deprecated :( )

In the OnConnection method you should add your command:

```
public void OnConnection( object application, ext_ConnectMode connectMode, object addInInst, ref Array custom )
{
    _applicationObject = (DTE2)application;
    if (connectMode == ext_ConnectMode.ext_cm_AfterStartup || connectMode == ext_ConnectMode.ext_cm_Startup)
    {
        Commands2 commands = (Commands2)_applicationObject.Commands;

        try
        {
            //Add a command to the Commands collection:
            Command command = commands.AddNamedCommand2(_addInInstance, "MyAddinMenuBar", "MyAddinMenuBar", "Executes the command for MyAddinMenuBar", true, 59, ref contextGUIDS, (int)vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusSupported + (int)vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusEnabled, (int)vsCommandStyle.vsCommandStylePictAndText, vsCommandControlType.vsCommandControlTypeButton);
        }
        catch (System.ArgumentException)
        {
            //If we are here, bla, bla... (Auto generated)
        }
    }
}
```

Note: you can find how parameters are act at the reference of [AddNamedCommand2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte80.commands2.addnamedcommand2%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)
The template created version would be also fine, but naturaly it worth to name your command properly.

After that you need to add your logic to `Exec` method:

```
public void Exec( string commandName, vsCommandExecOption executeOption, ref object varIn, ref object varOut, ref bool handled )
{
    handled = false;
    if (executeOption == vsCommandExecOption.vsCommandExecOptionDoDefault)
    {
        if (commandName == "MyAddinMenuBar.Connect.MyAddinMenuBar")
        {
            List<string> args = (varIn as string).Split(' ').ToList();

            TextSelection ts;
            ts = (TextSelection)_applicationObject.ActiveDocument.Selection;
            EditPoint ep = (ts.ActivePoint).CreateEditPoint();

            ep.StartOfDocument();

            do
            {
                string actualLine = ep.GetLines(ep.Line, ep.Line + 1);

                if (args.TrueForAll(filter => actualLine.Contains(filter)))
                {
                    _applicationObject.ExecuteCommand("Edit.GoTo", ep.Line.ToString());
                    _applicationObject.ExecuteCommand("Edit.ToggleOutliningExpansion");
                }

                ep.LineDown();
            } while (!ep.AtEndOfDocument);

            handled = true;
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Note: Name you given to the command is checked in exec.

Than you can build.

Deployment of Add-In can happen through an `[ProjectName].AddIn` file in `..\Documents\Visaul Studio 20[XY]\AddIns\`. (Created by the template, you should copy if you move the Add-In elsewhere)
You should place your Add-In assembly where the <kbd>Assembly</kbd> element of the mentioned file you set to point. To change version you should modify the text in <kbd>Version</kbd> element.

After you deployed and started Studio, you should activate the Add-In in the manager in `Tools`menu.

You need to expand all collapsable section in your code file (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> with C# IDE settigs).
This is required because I found only a way to invert the state of collapsion. If you find better command, you can change it.

Next you should activate Command Window to use the the created command. 
Now only you need to type your commands name, like this:

```
MyAddinMenuBar.Connect.MyAddinMenuBar #ifdef PROJNAME_DEBUG
```

Hopefully magic will happen.

This solution is independent of language of code you edit so pretty multifunctional.